# How to automatically export data from silverlight to local disk

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, export

I am running unit testing in silverlight.
I have the test data and I need to export it to local disk without user interaction.

I have thinked to export a file but it seems that it requires user interaction.
I thought I could try a local process that listens for silverlight data on a connection, which saves the data automatically, but didnt find if it is possible and how.

Can anyone help me on how to automatically export data from silverlight to local disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with a local server, it provide http web server, policy server and a socket listener.

The server run and:
- listen as http server for silverlight page requests.
- listen on a local port for silverlight test results encoded as xml
- listen on another port as a policy server, because silverlight need it to connect on a socket

Next the server starts internet explorer pointing to his own web server, at unit test page,

When the tests are finished I get the test result data structure in silverlight, open the connection to the local server (validated by the policy server) and send to it the result encoded in a string.

The server have full access to local file system, so it can silently produce output.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answer on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148182/does-silverlight-3-have-access-to-local-file-system-open-excel-and-print-report). It shows how to access the local file system, however it does require user interaction.

I would just add a page to the web app that is hosting the silverlight plugin that allows you to store the data locally. You can the post your data and have your backend (asp.net I suppose) store the data locally. If you already use WCF to comunicate with your backend, you can use that instead.

Comment: I have solved with a local server, it provide http web server, policy server and a socket listener.

Comment: I also cred a version without the socket listener, encoded results are retourned as data of a POST call to the http server