# Save file locally from asp.net without "save as.."? Is ActiveX the only solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, activex

I'm in the process of building a web application in ASP.NET MVC C# (including ajax/jquery) and have to save a file locally to the client's hard drive.

I have another application that polls a directory for new files, so it's essential the files from the website ends up at that location so therefore showing a "save as.." won't work.

What alternatives do I have? (Sadly I can't rewrite that external application to work in any other way.)
Should I write the web application in silverlight instead?
Should I use an ActiveX object? ActiveX feels so 1995 though.. Are there any other variants nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll vote for Silverlight solution.

But instead of developing your site entirely with Silverlight, just write a small and hidden Silverlight component that would receive a remote file location and stores it in user's local file system.

Check this other answer in Stackoverflow:

- [Does Silverlight 3 have access to local file system, Open Excel, and print reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148182/does-silverlight-3-have-access-to-local-file-system-open-excel-and-print-report)

And watch this movie:

- http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/local-file-access/

Comment: just to add Application must be a Trusted Application

Comment: i do agree.. there are not much options.

Comment: Thanks Matías! I haven't thought of using silverlight as a component. I think I'll try that solution

Answer (score 0):

This would be a security feature in the browser. It is not acceptable to give a website access to a local folder without some sort of dialog. ActiveX may work, because it is much less secure.

Can you not find a different approach?

In the past I have made a local application in C# that simply uses HTTP requests to download files in a client-server model.

Comment: There will be a large user base on this application so I kind of have to go the website-route instead of installing windows apps for everyone. This small issue with saving a file to a folder is only 1% of the whole application, the rest of the functionality will work perfectly as a web application so I don't want to give up on the website :)